# run javascript oncer per user session?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this javascript which shows a div if a user clicks on a text area in my search form.

basically at the moment the search form is being pulled through to the home page using

```
<?php include(); ?>
```

When the user is on the homepage they click the text area and the div shows, they then go off the text area (onblur) and the div hides. this function happens just once and wont happen again.

however once the user hits search and the search is submitted the function starts again, so the user clicks in the text area and the div shows, they come off it and it hides. Same as before this happens just once.

i dont want the div to show each time the the user clicks on the text field, i only want them to see this div once, not matter what page they are on on the site.

I have put the javascript in the search.php file which is pulled trough onto the homepage and onto every other page on my site.

This is probably why the function is happening on every new page it goes to, but whilst i want the user to be able to access the search bar from anywhere on the site and whether they start there search on home.php or profiles.php or any other page i want the div to be show to the user only once, and not again for the entire session or cookie session.

is this possible, can someone please show me how?

thanks

```
<script>

        $(function() {
            $(".search_prompt").hide();
            var focusin_flag = false,
                focusout_flag = false;
            $("#text").focusin(function() {
                if (!focusin_flag) {
                    $(".search_prompt").show();
                    focusin_flag = true;
                }
            }).focusout(function () {
                if (!focusout_flag ) {
                    $(".search_prompt").hide();
                    focusout_flag = true;
                } 
                function timeout_init() {
        setTimeout('search_prompt()', 2000);

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

SEARCH SCRIPT:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="dosearch" value="1">
    <input type="text" id="text" name="query" class="searchbox" placeholder="Search Name/Location" style="width:120px;"/>
    <input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/search.png" height="19" width="20" class="searchbutton" name="submit" value="Start Search" />
</form>

<?php
//PHP CODE STARTS HERE

if(isset($_GET['dosearch'])){

// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="";
$db_tb_atr_name="display_name";

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);


$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT *,MATCH(display_name, location, sex, ethnicity, hobbies, station, age, weight_st, weight_lb, height_ft, height_in, build) AGAINST ('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM ptb_stats WHERE MATCH(display_name, location, sex, ethnicity, hobbies, station, age, weight_st, weight_lb, height_ft, height_in, build) AGAINST('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 5");
echo "<div class=\"search-results\">";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))

{

    echo "<div class=\"text\"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$data_fetch['user_id']}\" class=\"search\">";
    echo "<div class=\"spacing\"><img width=35px height= 30px src=\"data/photos/{$data_fetch['user_id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgridsearch\"/> "; 
     echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
    echo "</a></div></div>";

}
echo "<div class=\"morebutton-search\"><a href=\"search_results.php?query=$query\" \">+ view more results</a></div>";




mysql_close();
}

?>
```

Comment: So you are wanting the js function to only work once, if I read this correctly.

Comment: Sounds like a session cookie is what you are looking for.

Comment: create a session boolean variable $SESSION["hasSearched"] set it to false and when they do a search set that variable to true. check the bool before you include the script for the popup. not sure exactly how you are doing the search and including the script but sounds like that would work?

Comment: yes class but per session so it doesnt start the function again each different page the user is on

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal, but I'd recommend setting a `$_SESSION` variable the first time the user hits that page (or performs whatever action you only want performed once). Then, before the JavaScript is included, check to see if that session variable is set. If so, don't include the JavaScript. If not, include it.

It would look something like this:

```
// User just performed action for the first time.
$_SESSION['saw_div'] = true;
```

Then, later :

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['saw_div']) || $_SESSION['saw_div'] == false): ?>
    <script>
        // Include your JS script
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: tried this but it keeps the div vissible, and doesnt go away when the user clicks out the text area. its also visible from page load and it should only be visible from when the user clicks on the text area.